# Numbering according to order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this in MySQL:

```
name     position
apple    0
banana   0
candy    0
```

And I want to update it to look like this:

```
name     position
apple    1
banana   2
candy    3
```

That is, I want to update the column `position` to indicate where the row is when ordered alphabetically by `name`.  I'd really, really, *really* like to do this without using a variable.  Also, the real table has 1000 entries in it, so it would help if the procedure were moderately efficient.

Comment: So you mean order the table alphabetically and then insert the correct position number for each row?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution in mysql without using variables.

And since you asked "like to do this without using a variable" - then the final answer is "It is impossible in mysql"

Anyway, this is a solution with variables, just to notice:

```
select name,
       @I := @I + 1
  from tblname,
       (select @I := 0) x;
```

Comment: Other people feel differently.

Comment: @Malvolio: checked answer doesn't make a deal with duplicates. If you have any duplicates (you did not mention either column is unique or not, so we mention there can be) - then you'll get wrong positions.

Answer (score 2):

Without using a variable:

```
  SELECT a.name, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM YOUR_TABLE b
           WHERE b.name <= a.name) AS position   
    FROM YOUR_TABLE a
ORDER BY position
```

The problem is, duplicates will get the same position number.

Variables is the only option to get no duplicate position values:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
  JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

...without creating a table with a column called `position` that is set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

MySQL doesn't support analytic functions such as ROW_NUMBER, which is what you'd use for this situation.

Comment: "without creating a table with a column called position that is set to AUTO_INCREMENT".  Hmmmm, why would I want to do without that...

Comment: As it happens, in my problem, duplicates *should* get the same position number.

Comment: @Malvolio: well, "duplicates should get the same position" -- you had to specify this in the question, before you accuse answerers, ok?

Comment: @zerkms -- the only possibilities are 1. duplicates are impossible, 2. duplicates are given the same position, or 3. duplicates are arbitrarily given different positions.  Perhaps if (3) is added to the question, there is no pure SQL/DML solution, but the problem never occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable in plain SQL.  Try something like:

```
UPDATE mytable AS master SET position = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable AS counter WHERE counter.name < master.name
);
```

Efficient?  Hah.  But even 1000 entries is considered a "small" table, so it'll go faster than you think.

Hope this helps!

**PS:** Dunno what you're using this for, but it's quite possible you could do it faster and more efficently with an index on `mytable.name` and a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: I am (roughly) putting a message in each person's description, saying "Congratulations, you are # *n* " -- so `LIMIT` won't do anything for me.

Comment: If I could, I would take a ¼ point off for the fencepost error: the first row would be numbered 0 with your method, instead of 1.

Comment: Also want to notice that such query is less performant than one with variables.

Comment: Bummer!  `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'master' for update in FROM clause`  Stupid MySQL ruining a great answer.

Comment: @Malvolio - Whoops!  Shoulda tested that with an update rather than just a select...

Comment: @Malvolio - I stumbled across something interesting when I was researching this, though:  You can achieve this by making a new table `like` the old one + an `auto_increment` column, then using `insert` + `select` + `order by`.  See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) - it's the last thing before the comments section.  And I was able to get it to work with the `auto_increment` field having a regular index; it doesn't need to be the primary key, like in their examples.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @Xavier_Holt, it does.  @OMG_Ponies discarded a similar idea, but didn't say why.